# ESLint rule for preventing object initialization in React props

Tags: reactjs, eslint

One of the bad React practices is to use object initialization directly in React props, such as double curly braces, and arrow functions:

```
<Foo bar={{ baz: 1 }} />
<Foo onClick={() => handler()} />
```

Since they trigger re-render even with memorized props.

Is there any ESLint rule that can prevent these?

Comment: Same, looking for a solution to warn developers about the memoization failure provoked by this syntax.